# Best Practice for building a GraphQL Schema with

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, graphql, graphql-schema

Currently learning GraphQL with Express and Typescript. I am trying to build a Root Schema with Queries and Mutations. I have found a way to do it but I think this isn't the best way to build out a GraphQL schema. Wondering what everyone else has seen in a professional setting as far as building a GraphQL Server.

First, building the fields out like so. The `UserType` and `AuthType` are GraphQLObjectTypes.

```
export const authMutationFields = {
  login: {
    type: AuthType,
    args,
    resolve: AuthService.login,
  },
....
};

export const userMutationFields = {
  deleteUser: {
    type: UserType,
    args: { userId: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) } },
    resolve: UserService.deleteUser,
  },
};
```

Then, merging these into the root query and mutation like so:

```
const mutationFields = () => ({ ...authMutationFields, ...userMutationFields });

const queryFields = () => ({ ...userQueryFields });

const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootMutation",
  description: "Root Mutation",
  fields: mutationFields,
});

const query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQuery",
  description: "Root Query",
  fields: queryFields,
});

export const rootSchema = new GraphQLSchema({ query, mutation });
```

While this works... It certainly doesn't seem like something you'd see in the wild. I could use the buildSchema but that seems like a method that doesn't scale well.

Thanks in advance!